# Enum in C++ Classes

Tags: c++, data-structures

I want to create a C++ room booking system which in it, I want to have one class for Members {Administrator, Staff, student}, and another class for types of rooms {lecture, auditorium, lab, ... }. The question is can use enum for both classes which specify it types. And then in the main method in another class there would be a problem, or not?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class room {

    enum roomType {

        main,
        exam,
        lecture
    };
}

// another class for members

class member {

    enum memberType {

        admin,
        staff,
        student
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is, but the code you have posted is OK except for missing semicolons at the end of class definitions

Comment: Have you tried this? Did you encounter any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine (except for missing `;` after the classes). Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>

class room {
public:
    enum roomType { main, exam, lecture };

    room(roomType t) : type(t) {}
private:
    roomType type;
};

// another class for members

class member {
public:
    enum memberType { admin, staff, student };

    member(memberType t) : type(t) {}
private:
    memberType type;
};

int main() {
    room r(room::lecture);
    member m(member::staff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `enum` to specify room type and member type, it is not a good approach.

1. If you need to add new room types and/or member types, you'll have to modify the classes, which are presumably in good working condition. This violates the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).
2. You will need to use `if/else` logic to deal with different room types and member types. Once again, when you add new room types and/or member types, you'll have to visit all the places where the said `if/else` logic used to account for the newly added types. It is another violation of the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

   Also, the `if/else` method tends to be buggy. It's easy to miss a type or two.

It will be better to use inheritance and create different types of rooms and members.

```
// room type and its sub-classes.

class room_t
{
}

class main_room_t : public room_t
{
};

class exam_room_t : public room_t
{
};

class lecture_room_t : public room_t
{
};

// member type and its sub-classes.

class member_t
{
};

class admin_t : public member_t 
{
};

class staff_t : public member_t 
{
};

class student_t : public member_t 
{
};
```

You'll need to add necessary `virtual` member functions to provide behavior to the classes.

Comment: Thank you, So in this case, I don't need enum anymore? and lots of repeated code?

Comment: @MahdiNajafi, No, you don't the `enum`s any more. I don't know about lots of repeated code -- it depends to an extent on your requirements. Overall, it should be the same amount of code but better organized.